# Mobile/tablet version of site lacks editor buttons for questions and answers

Tags: feature-request

As a user who often writes or pastes snippets of code, on portable devices I expirience complete inability to markup copied code properly or markup text. [image]

The same text editor is used for answers. Switching to "desktop mode" doesn't do much, instead I get older version of mobile interface.

Answers to this question and following edits to them are results of this behaviour
[Struct inside struct: 'Illegal reference to non-static member' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294539/struct-inside-struct-illegal-reference-to-non-static-member-error)

DIsable\Enable Responsiveness in footnote is not available as well, the "Full site" link there doesn't result in same interface (and no way switch back). THe buttons in that mode seems to act up when clicked , causing scale change or scrolling.

Comment: What happens if you click “Enable Responsiveness” or “Disable Responsiveness”?

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Excuse me, where? That's all what is on page (except the bottom black line, tag edit and blue button, which are hidden by keyboard)

Comment: It’s a link in the footer, at the bottom left. There’s also a “Mobile” link. Have you tried that, too? By “Switching to ‘desktop mode’”, did you mean in the browser itself?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh, it's "full site", gives same result as using browser menu. That works, though looks a bit broken,  I'll loose entered text though. and yes, mobile browsers now can "hide" their nature to server to request desktop version. Tbh, my device got 2k screen, there is no trouble to use d3sktop version, but somehow I get a cropped one anyway.

Comment: Well, mobile answerers are a minority (me being one of them), thats why the support is lacking in many areas, e.g. snippets, review queues, question history ...

Comment: Just switch to the full version of the site, with the link in the footer.

Comment: @JonasWilms kinda strange, pretty much anyone I know who uses stackexchange , use it from mobile, netbook or tablet. Usual enterprise policy, especially IT , government, research etc. is to block social networks and login is based on them. Plus it's really annoying that kiosks, netbooks and and tablets are being bunched with phones. Android != phone, there is even desktop attempts at use android OS.